# Вложенный контейнер и алгоритмы std

Tags: stl, массивы, c++, c++11

Предположим, есть подобный контейнер:

```
std::array<std::array<int,5>, 3> container;
```

Который представляет собой матрицу 3x5. 
Как можно элегантно заполнить данный контейнер, не прибегая к:

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
 for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
     container[i][j] = someVal;   
....
```

Comment: А чем не подходит

    for (auto &row: container) row.fill(value);

Или нужно обязательно в функциональном стиле?

Comment: Не обязательно. Про этот метод не знал, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Можно через [список инициализации](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)

```
std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 5> container =          
            {{{5, 8, 2}, 
              {8, 3, 1}, 
              {5, 3, 9},
              {5, 3, 9},
              {5, 3, 9}}};
```

Здесь мы добавили дополнительные фигурные скобки для инициализации array внутри array.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте функцию `array::fill`:

```
for (auto& row: container)
  row.fill(value);
```